# Cache invalidation in revel framework

Tags: go, revel

I'm looking for a way to invalidate cached static content upon version change. Preferably using commit id to invalidate. Is there anyway to do this in revel framework ?

I would prefer if its automatic but I could live with updating it each time if its a single place I have to edit.

The current strategy I have is changing the name of the static content route to include version but this requires several changes. In places that feel unnatural, for instance in the routing file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it manually via a config variable and an intercept method.

### resourceversion.go

Create this file in your controllers folder:

```
package controllers

import (
    "github.com/revel/revel"
)

// interceptor method, called before every request. 
// Sets a template variable to the resourceVersion read from app.conf
func SetVersion(c *revel.Controller) revel.Result {
    c.RenderArgs["resourceVersion"] = revel.Config.StringDefault("resourceVersion", "1")
    return nil
}
```

### init.go

In the init() method, append this line:

```
revel.InterceptMethod(controllers.SetVersion, revel.BEFORE)
```

### templates

In your templates, where you want to use the resource version:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/public/css/style.css?{{.resourceVersion}}">
```

### app.conf

And finally, the place you will update it - add this line above the dev section to apply to dev and prod, or have a different one in each, whatever suits.

```
resourceVersion=20150716
```

I guess you could create a script as part of your build and release process that would automatically edit this config variable.

Comment: Is it possible to use a syntax like /public/<resourceVersion>/css instead of the query parameter?

Comment: Yes, that works fine - just change the template to whatever format you want.  _/public/{{.resourceVersion}}/css/style.css_

Comment: It works but how would I go about making the content serve on that route? preferably without changing folder names. Sorry for all the though questions Im quite new to revel and go aswell.

Comment: Sorry, you're right - that doesn't work. You could try adding a variable into your route - like _GET     /public/:version/*filepath              Static.Serve("public")_.   That seems to work, but seems to me like it might have issues with that variable part matching real paths, so you'd need to be a bit careful.

Comment: I'm trying to extend the Static controller at the moment with a new controller that strips the version part out and passes to the normal Static Controller but im having some problems with it.

Comment: My first thought was to try and change the Static controller, but that seemed like it was changing too much. Should certainly be possible though, there isn't much code in it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83415/discussion-between-pablo-karlsson-and-colin-nicholson).

Answer (score 0):

I did the things that Colin Nicholson suggested but I also created a controller called staticversionbasedcacheinvalidator and placed it in the controller folder. You can find it below. It allows you to ignore the first part of the request string allowing you to use a wildcard path to your public folder. For instance I use this route config row

```
GET     /public/*filepath                             StaticVersionbasedCacheInvalidator.Serve("public")
```

I then added the {{.resourceVersion}} in my route instead of as a query param.

```
package controllers

import (
    "github.com/revel/revel"
    "os"
    fpath "path/filepath"
    "strings"
    "syscall"
)

type StaticVersionbasedCacheInvalidator struct {
    *revel.Controller
}

// This method handles requests for files. The supplied prefix may be absolute
// or relative. If the prefix is relative it is assumed to be relative to the
// application directory. The filepath may either be just a file or an
// additional filepath to search for the given file. This response may return
// the following responses in the event of an error or invalid request;
//   403(Forbidden): If the prefix filepath combination results in a directory.
//   404(Not found): If the prefix and filepath combination results in a non-existent file.
//   500(Internal Server Error): There are a few edge cases that would likely indicate some configuration error outside of revel.
//
// Note that when defining routes in routes/conf the parameters must not have
// spaces around the comma.
//   Bad:  StaticVersionbasedCacheInvalidator.Serve("public/img", "favicon.png")
//   Good: StaticVersionbasedCacheInvalidator.Serve("public/img","favicon.png")
//
// Examples:
// Serving a directory
//   Route (conf/routes):
//     GET /public/{<.*>filepath} StaticVersionbasedCacheInvalidator.Serve("public")
//   Request:
//     public/js/sessvars.js
//   Calls
//     StaticVersionbasedCacheInvalidator.Serve("public","js/sessvars.js")
//
// Serving a file
//   Route (conf/routes):
//     GET /favicon.ico StaticVersionbasedCacheInvalidator.Serve("public/img","favicon.png")
//   Request:
//     favicon.ico
//   Calls:
//     StaticVersionbasedCacheInvalidator.Serve("public/img", "favicon.png")
func (c StaticVersionbasedCacheInvalidator) Serve(prefix, filepath string) revel.Result {

    firstSplice := strings.Index(filepath,"/")
    if(firstSplice != -1) {
            filepath = filepath[firstSplice:len(filepath)];
    }

    // Fix for #503.
    prefix = c.Params.Fixed.Get("prefix")
    if prefix == "" {
        return c.NotFound("")
    }

    return serve(c, prefix, filepath)
}

// This method allows modules to serve binary files. The parameters are the same
// as StaticVersionbasedCacheInvalidator.Serve with the additional module name pre-pended to the list of
// arguments.
func (c StaticVersionbasedCacheInvalidator) ServeModule(moduleName, prefix, filepath string) revel.Result {
    // Fix for #503.
    prefix = c.Params.Fixed.Get("prefix")
    if prefix == "" {
        return c.NotFound("")
    }

    var basePath string
    for _, module := range revel.Modules {
        if module.Name == moduleName {
            basePath = module.Path
        }
    }

    absPath := fpath.Join(basePath, fpath.FromSlash(prefix))

    return serve(c, absPath, filepath)
}


// This method allows StaticVersionbasedCacheInvalidator serving of application files in a verified manner.
func serve(c StaticVersionbasedCacheInvalidator, prefix, filepath string) revel.Result {
    var basePath string
    if !fpath.IsAbs(prefix) {
        basePath = revel.BasePath
    }

    basePathPrefix := fpath.Join(basePath, fpath.FromSlash(prefix))
    fname := fpath.Join(basePathPrefix, fpath.FromSlash(filepath))
    // Verify the request file path is within the application's scope of access
    if !strings.HasPrefix(fname, basePathPrefix) {
        revel.WARN.Printf("Attempted to read file outside of base path: %s", fname)
        return c.NotFound("")
    }

    // Verify file path is accessible
    finfo, err := os.Stat(fname)
    if err != nil {
        if os.IsNotExist(err) || err.(*os.PathError).Err == syscall.ENOTDIR {
            revel.WARN.Printf("File not found (%s): %s ", fname, err)
            return c.NotFound("File not found")
        }
        revel.ERROR.Printf("Error trying to get fileinfo for '%s': %s", fname, err)
        return c.RenderError(err)
    }

    // Disallow directory listing
    if finfo.Mode().IsDir() {
        revel.WARN.Printf("Attempted directory listing of %s", fname)
        return c.Forbidden("Directory listing not allowed")
    }

    // Open request file path
    file, err := os.Open(fname)
    if err != nil {
        if os.IsNotExist(err) {
            revel.WARN.Printf("File not found (%s): %s ", fname, err)
            return c.NotFound("File not found")
        }
        revel.ERROR.Printf("Error opening '%s': %s", fname, err)
        return c.RenderError(err)
    }
    return c.RenderFile(file, revel.Inline)
}
```